# How does maven resolve a parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dependency-management, multi-module

I came accross a problem and I want to **understand** it.

### Story

Maven version was 3.2.1. I had a multi-module project structure like this:

```
mainmoduleA
-pom.xml
-submoduleB
--pom.xml
--submoduleC
---pom.xml
-submoduleD
--pom.xml
--submoduleE
---pom.xml
```

The submodules are always the child of the module in the parent folder. None of them have `relativePath` in the `parent` element in their POM, which means as far as I know `../pom.xml`. The problem was, that `submoduleC` has become a new dependency, and `submoduleE` was already depending on `submoduleC`. The version of the new dependency of `submoduleC` was managed in `mainmoduleA`. In the **local repository and in the company repository was still an old version of `mainmoduleA`**, which did not contain that managed version. The workspace folder structure however contained the correct `mainmoduleA` POM. **If I have built `submoduleE` alone**, I have got a warning that the transitive dependencies of `submoduleC` will be ignored because of the missing managed version, and the **results were compilation errors**.

### Resolution Priority

**What is the order of the possibilities used by maven to look up a parent pom?**

Based on my experience above:

1. maven local repository
2. maven remote repository
3. tracking it down in the folder structure based on the `relativePath` tags of the `parent` tags.

Am I right with the statements above? Can you prove it somehow? I did not find any relevant documentation.

Comment: Strange, my experience was rather that, if the tracking of the `relativePath`paths was OK, local directory was the first in the order.

Comment: @Tome:For me too. But it behaved today different and I became confused.

Comment: First test with such multi module builds is. Clean the whole local repository and try to build via `mvn clean package` this must work without any issue otherwise something else is wrong.